# Oracle Virtual Trader's Case Statement syntex question

Tags: oracle

To all Wisdoms,

I am currently using a module called Virtual trader in Oracle 12.1.3 with RDBMS 11.2 to automatize excel calculations. It essentially coverts Excel logic to a syntex in Oracle.

For example, xxcp_cu_cpa.get_tp_rates({D1040},{D1031},{D1047},'Rate 4') means that go to TP Rates table and get Rate 4.

Currently, I have the following table to build with some Case statement. I only know a Case statement with 1 logic , such as case when to_number({D2222}) > to_number({D21111}) then to_number({D2226} - {D2432}) else to_number({D2127}) end

Rule          Volume range  Gap             Applicable %
Up to        1,000,000,000  1,000,000,000   2.40%
Up to       1,500,000,000   500,000,000     2.20%
Up to       2,000,000,000   500,000,000     1.90%
Above       2,000,000,000        -          1.70%

So, any feedback on building a case statement with those 4 logics are hugely appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `CASE` like this

```
case when volume <= 1000000000 then 2.4
     when volume <= 1500000000 then 2.2
     when volume <= 2000000000 then 1.9 
     else 1.7 end as perc
```

Test case

```
with dt as (
select 1000000000 volume from dual union all
select 1000000001 volume from dual union all
select 1500000000 volume from dual union all
select 1500000001 volume from dual union all
select 2000000000 volume from dual union all
select 2100000001 volume from dual)
select volume,
  case when volume <= 1000000000 then 2.4
       when volume <= 1500000000 then 2.2
       when volume <= 2000000000 then 1.9 
       else 1.7 end as perc
from dt;

    VOLUME       PERC
---------- ----------
1000000000        2,4
1000000001        2,2
1500000000        2,2
1500000001        1,9
2000000000        1,9
2100000001        1,7
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! I will test out. Have a good holiday !